# "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" in a Hyperledger Fabric-Composer network, after a restart from a snapshot of Virtualbox machines

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm making some tests about a configuration of multi-machine and multi-organization blockchain network based on Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Composer. In my configuration I have two Virtualbox Machines with one organization for each machine. Once I create the Fabric network between the two machines (using Docker Swarm to connect the Docker Containers of the two machines), and I load a smart contract, I want to keep the state of the network even when I shutdown the PC. I tried to use the snapshots of the VMs to keep the state of the two VMs, but I didn't solve the problem, because when I wake up the VMs and I try to use the smart contract I obtain a "SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE" error. So, my question is.. How can I solve this problem, and what is the best way to handle this situation?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: i dont understand why use both docker and virtualbox, why not only docker itself?

Comment: Because I want to simulate a scenario where in production I'll use physical machines. So, in the test phase i'm using VMs where each virtual machine represents an hypotetical physical machine.

Comment: can u upload th screenshot of the result on th terminal~